JSON restructuring using ADF
I have a business requirement to process a JSON API using Azure Data Factory, preferably avoiding alternative code-based functions like Azure Functions. The API has the form:
{ 
  "parentProperty": {
       "key1": {
           "key2": {
               "property1": x,
               "property2: y
           },
           "key3": {
               "property1": z,
               "property2: a
           }
       },
       "key4": {
           "key5": {
               "property1": b,
               "property2: c
           },
           "key6": {
               "property1": d,
               "property2: e
           }
       }
  }
}

This needs to be transformed into a table like:



Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4




key1
key2
x
y


key1
key3
z
a


key4
key5
b
c


key4
key6
d
e



This would be very easy in code such as a function, but the operators in Azure Data Factory looked limited for this type of transformations. Is there a way to use the native operators to transform this JSON?
Update
Under current testing, the source and sinks are:
Source: JSON Blob Storage
Sink: Delimited Text Blob Storage
Transformations Attempted

Select Column - cannot do this as we the values of the top level properties may change. This data structure is more like a map/dictionary and we cannot be certain of it's structure.
Derived Column - similarly - this operator is problematic as it cannot work unless the JSON property structured is known.


Can you provide what you have tried so far and what is your source and target here?

Updated above. The struggle is the fact the property values in JSON are not known, and the property values themselves that are labelled keyX are actually cell values in the tabular structure of a CSV / relational database. There doesn't appear to be an obvious way that I can see to map these dictionary/map style JSON objects to a tabular structure in ADF (without code).

Are the number of keys in each hierarchy are limited to a number? I mean do you know the count of those?

They are limited, but not known up front, and they could change in the future. I would prefer to not make any assumptions about what the keys might be in case they change in the future.

Is this the same structure in every hierarchy?

Yes. I guess it's essentially the equivalent of a dictionary/map of a dictionary/map which then has a couple of values. I need it to be in a 2d tabular format so it can be processed in ADF.

Check the below answer and let me know if it fits your requirement or not.

Thanks, I've tried it on our example, and it does work. A lot more complex than a code-based solution, but it does allow us to do what we need to do without other tooling. Thanks for providing a worked example :).

You can achieve your requirement using the combination of select, derivedColumn and filter transformations in the dataflow like below.
But this approach will only work for this structure(3 level) and it will involve some manual operations.
Follow the below transformations in the dataflow.

Source - Add your JSON dataset here and make sure you select Single document in the JSON settings of the source.

derived Column2 - Create a column myjson and store the JSON string from parentProperty with expression toString(parentProperty).

select1 - Extract the inner keys in the parentProperty object using Rule-based mapping as new columns in select transformation.




derived Column1 - Create 2 columns named as columns and names. The columns column will store the array of extracted column names which are the first level key names while the names column will store the array of all keys in the JSON in the same order.
Use below expressions for those.
columns - filter(columnNames(),(#item!='myjson'))

names - slice(map(split(myjson,'":{'),split(#item,'"')[size(split(#item,'"'))]),1,size(map(split(myjson,'":{'),split(#item,'"')[size(split(#item,'"'))]))-1)


select2 - Remove the extracted columns from select1 and keep only the columns myjson,columns,names.

derivedColumn3 - Unfold the columns array column and store the result in a new column column1 with expression toString(unfold(columns)). This will contain the first level key names.

derivedColumn4 - Similarly unfold the names array column and store the result in a new column column2 with expression toString(unfold(columns)). This will be the second level key names but will have extra data. This will give the result like below. Here, the column1 and column2 contains the first level and second level keys but there will be duplicates and extra combinations.




filter1 - This will filter out the duplicate key rows by comparing both columns and also will remove the first level key names in the column2. Use the (column1!=column2) && (!contains(columns,#item==column2)) expression for this.

filter2 - This will filter out the correct combination rows of first and second level keys. Use the below expression for it.
(toInteger(split(find(mapIndex(names,concat(#item,'-',toString(#index))),instr(#item,column2)>0),'-')[2])>toInteger(split(find(mapIndex(names,concat(#item,'-',toString(#index))),instr(#item,column1)>0),'-')[2]))&&(divide(size(names),size(columns)))>(minus(toInteger(split(find(mapIndex(names,concat(#item,'-',toString(#index))),instr(#item,column2)>0),'-')[2]),toInteger(split(find(mapIndex(names,concat(#item,'-',toString(#index))),instr(#item,column1)>0),'-')[2])))

It will give the result like below.



derivedColumn5 - Create the new columns column3 and column4 to get the inner values. Use the below expression for this.
column3 - replace(split(split(split(myjson,column2)[2],':')[3],',')[1],'"','')

column4 - replace(replace(split(split(split(myjson,column2)[2],':')[4],',')[1],'"',''),'}','')

This will give the required columns.





select3 - Remove the extra columns here.
sink1 - Add your delimited text dataset and execute the dataflow from the pipeline.

Result csv file:

This is my Dataflow JSON for your reference:
{
    "name": "dataflow6",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "connstruct_json",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "construct_csv",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn4"
                },
                {
                    "name": "filter1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "filter2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn5"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select3"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          parentProperty as (key1 as (key2 as (property1 as string, property2 as string), key3 as (property1 as string, property2 as string)), key4 as (key5 as (property1 as string, property2 as string), key6 as (property1 as string, property2 as string)))",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     documentForm: 'singleDocument') ~> source1",
                "derivedColumn2 select(mapColumn(",
                "          each(parentProperty,match(true())),",
                "          myjson",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "select1 derive(columns = filter(columnNames(),(#item!='myjson')),",
                "          names = slice(map(split(myjson,'\":{'),split(#item,'\"')[size(split(#item,'\"'))]),1,size(map(split(myjson,'\":{'),split(#item,'\"')[size(split(#item,'\"'))]))-1)) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "source1 derive(myjson = toString(parentProperty)) ~> derivedColumn2",
                "derivedColumn1 select(mapColumn(",
                "          myjson,",
                "          columns,",
                "          names",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select2",
                "select2 derive(column1 = toString(unfold(columns))) ~> derivedColumn3",
                "derivedColumn3 derive(column2 = toString(unfold(names))) ~> derivedColumn4",
                "derivedColumn4 filter((column1!=column2) && (!contains(columns,#item==column2))) ~> filter1",
                "filter1 filter((toInteger(split(find(mapIndex(names,concat(#item,'-',toString(#index))),instr(#item,column2)>0),'-')[2])>toInteger(split(find(mapIndex(names,concat(#item,'-',toString(#index))),instr(#item,column1)>0),'-')[2]))&&(divide(size(names),size(columns)))>(minus(toInteger(split(find(mapIndex(names,concat(#item,'-',toString(#index))),instr(#item,column2)>0),'-')[2]),toInteger(split(find(mapIndex(names,concat(#item,'-',toString(#index))),instr(#item,column1)>0),'-')[2])))) ~> filter2",
                "filter2 derive(column3 = replace(split(split(split(myjson,column2)[2],':')[3],',')[1],'\"',''),",
                "          column4 = replace(replace(split(split(split(myjson,column2)[2],':')[4],',')[1],'\"',''),'}','')) ~> derivedColumn5",
                "derivedColumn5 select(mapColumn(",
                "          column1,",
                "          column2,",
                "          column3,",
                "          column4",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select3",
                "select3 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     umask: 0022,",
                "     preCommands: [],",
                "     postCommands: [],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}

